# Detecting duplicate images by hashing a stream

Tags: node.js

I'm piping images onto a local filesystem using Request, and attempting to recognize duplicates by hashing the received buffers. However, when I attempt to pipe a duplicate image, the received buffer is for some reason coming in slightly differently each time, with 1-2 bytes changed (out of hundreds of thousands). Yet, even just a one byte difference is enough for my hash to come out completely different and not mark the image as a duplicate which it ought to be- how can I avoid this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Hash functions, by design, will give different results for different inputs.

It sounds as though you're trying to detect *similar* images, which is a rather different, and very difficult, problem. Search the literature for information on perceptual image hashing for more information.

Comment: No, I am not attempting to detect similar images- as written in my question I piped the same image from the same source multiple times, and the received buffer differed by 1-2 bytes each time, causing the hash to turn out differently. I am asking if there is away to overcome the discrepancy in streaming, not detect similarity between close images.

Comment: Ah, just reread my question and I can see how the wording could be confusing- when I said "slight differences each time", I meant in the data received, not the image itself. I'll change that to make it clearer.

Comment: Er… if you're reading the same file and getting different data each time, either 1) your hard drive is failing catastrophically, or 2) there is something wrong with your file reading logic. But we can't debug that from the information you've provided.

Comment: Indeed, that was the case. I rechecked the code and found I had mistakenly been hashing the buffer on the 'end' event for the pipe instead of the 'end' event for the initial stream operation, causing it to occur just before the stream itself had completed (and thus the buffer was not fully completed). Thank you!